# Run ruby website from external

Tags: ruby, rack

I want to call a ruby website that runs on my pc, from external.
Locally, I use rackup to run the HTTPServer and the ruby and browse to localhost:9292.

How can I reach this from another pc?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Greetings
Schakron

Comment: You have to forward port 9292 from your router to the PC in question, and then visit your_external_ip_address:9292.

Practically, deploying to heroku is probably just as easy.

Comment: This depends a lot on how your network is set up, thought it could be as easy as forwarding ports in your router as @DVG said. In the long term you'll probably want to deploy to a more robust hosting solution.

Comment: Is this "other pc" on the same LAN as your pc, or is it outside your network? If it's the same lan, it may be as simple as accessing your pc's IP address from the other - `http://your.ip.address.here:9292` rather than localhost. Though you *may* have to open ports on local firewall software

Comment: I am in a local network with the other pc. I already tried binding it on 0.0.0.0 using
`rackup -o 0.0.0.0 -p 9292`.
I have enabled the port 9292 on my firewall.
Anyways I cant access from another pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this within your local network using your computer's IP address.

So for example, if you're running the localhost on a computer with IP `31.0.12.62`, you can access it from any other machine in the same local network by entering this in the browser url bar:

```
http://31.0.12.62:9292/
```

Comment: Actually I thought this would work as well. But as things turned out, it doesnt. I really have enabled the port, but I just cannot access